# Testing rx-observables from Futures/Iterables

Tags: scala, rx-java, reactive-programming, scalatest, rx-scala

I have:

```
val observable: Observable[Int] = Observable.from(List(5))
```

and I can test that the input list is indeed passed on to the observable by testing:

```
materializeValues(observable) should contain (5)
```

where `materializeValues` is:

```
def materializeValues[T](observable: Observable[T]): List[T] = {
  observable.toBlocking.toIterable.toList
}
```

Now, if I create an observable from a future, I can't seem to use `materializeValues` for the test as the test times out. So if I have:

```
val futVal = Future.successful(5)
val observable: Observable[Int] = Observable.from(futVal)
materializeValues(observable) should contain(5)
```

it times out and does not pass the test. What is different in the process of materializing these two observables, which leads to me not being able to block on it?

Also, what is the idomatic way of testing an observable? Is there any way of doing it without calling `toBlocking`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior with timeout of the `Observable` from a `Future`. Maybe you have some problems with your implicit `ExecutionContext`? Also providing a [mcve] is always a good idea.

Comment: Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/ShahOdin/74fb61e61f98f65261f491d73628d993 `ExecutionContext` is from `AsyncTestSuite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you use `AsyncWordSpecLike` (by the way why `AsyncWordSpecLike` instead of `AsyncWordSpec`?). `AsyncWordSpecLike`/`AsyncWordSpec` are designed to simplify testing `Future`. Unfortunately `Observable` is a more powerful abstraction that can't be easily mapped onto a `Future`.

Particularly `AsyncWordSpecLike`/`AsyncWordSpec` allow your tests to return `Future[Assertion]`. To make it possible it provides custom implicit `ExecutionContext` that it can force to execute everything and know when all scheduled jobs have finished. However the same custom `ExecutionContext` is the reason why your second code doesn't work: processing of the scheduled jobs starts only after execution of your test code has finished but your code blocks on the `futVal` because unlucklily for you callback registered in `Future.onComplete` is scheduled to be run on the `ExecutionContext`. It means that you have a kind of dead-lock with your own thread.

I'm not sure what is the official way to test `Observable` on Scala. In Java I think [TestSubscriber](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html) is the suggested tool. As I said `Observable` is fundamentally more powerful thing than `Future` so I think to test `Observable` you should avoid using `AsyncWordSpecLike`/`AsyncWordSpec`. If you switch to use `FlatSpec` or `WordSpec`, you can do something like this:

```
class MyObservableTestSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  val testValue = 5

  "observables" should {

    "be testable if created from futures" in {
      val futVal = Future.successful(testValue)
      val observable = Observable.from(futVal)

      val subscriber = TestSubscriber[Int]()
      observable(subscriber)
      subscriber.awaitTerminalEvent
      // now after awaitTerminalEvent you can use various subscriber.assertXyz methods
      subscriber.assertNoErrors
      subscriber.assertValues(testValue)
      // or you can use Matchers as 
      subscriber.getOnNextEvents should contain(testValue)
    }

  }

}
```